# Crud con laravel y Ajax

Tags: javascript, laravel, ajax

estoy intentando hacer un CRUD con laravel 8 y Ajax, pero cuando quiero insertar un registro me muestra que tengo problemas con la ruta y arroja el el error 404, con la otra ruta mostrar no tengo problemas, pero con esta para insertar no me funciona.

estas son mis rutas en mi archivo web.php:

```
Route::get('/',PageController::class);
Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');

Route::get('system.logistica', [BodegaController::class, 'index'])->name('logistica');

Route::post('system.logistica/one/{id}', [BodegaController::class, 'mostrar'])->name('logistica.mostrar');

// Esta es la ruta que no funciona
Route::post('system.guiaingresos',[BodegaController::class,'insert'])->name('guiaingresos.insert');
```

este es mi función en mi archivo js

```js
function temporal()
{
   const codigobarra=$('#Txt_serie').val();
   const sku_ext=$('#Txt_codigo').val();
   const Idservicio=$('#Txt_servicio').val(); 
   const Numguia=$('#Txt_numguia').val(); 
   const Idmaterial=$('#Txt_idmaterial').val();
   const Idproveedor=$('#Txt_prov').val();
   const Numcantidad=$('#Txt_cant').val();
   const identificador=$('#Txt_identificador').val();
   const Numfila=$('#Txt_fila').val();
   const usuario=$('#Txt_user').val();
    
   $.ajax(
        {
            url:"{{ route('guiaingresos.insert') }}", // aqui llamo a la ruta insert
            type:'POST',
            data: {
                _token:$('input[name="_token"]').val(),
                temp_mat_id:Idmaterial,
                tem_mst_id:1,
                temp_ser_id:Idservicio,
                temp_serie:codigobarra,
                temp_guia:Numguia,
                temp_pro_id:Idproveedor,
                temp_identificador:identificador,
                temp_nwa_id:1,
                temp_use_id:usuario

            },
            success:function (response) {
                if(response){
                alert('OK');
                }
            }
            
                
            });
         
    
}
```

y este es mi controlador con la función insert

```
 public function insert(Request $request)
{
   $id_usuario=$request->temp_use_id;
   
   return ($id_usuario);

   //por ahora solo quiero comprobar que llego a la ruta y a la función de mi 
     controlador
    }
```

Espero me puedan ayudar, saludos!!!

Comment: En tu controlador no hay ningun `logistica.insert`

Comment: @Juan Rivera gracias por responder, la verdad me habia equivocado al pasar mi código pero a la ruta que quiero ir desde mi js es esta {{ route('guiaingresos.insert')}},  y mi función se llamar insert en mi controlador

Comment: si el Ajax esta dentro de un archivo js separado del Blade, este no sabe interpretar las directivas de Blade, por ende no recibe la ruta correctamente, lo que puedes haces es embeberlo en el Blade o poniendo la ruta completa en la url del ajax.

Comment: Si tiene el funcion en un archivo aparte como dice @tecnobyte no reconoce la {{route()}} de laravel, pero puedes hacer a que tu funcion js temporal() reciba la ruta como parametro y se la mandas desde el blade 

temporal(ruta){ } 

Y en el $.ajax donde esta la Ruta, coloca la variable ruta que es la que ingresa desde el blade, entonces podras tener en un archivo js tu función y que el blade mande la ruta a donde ejecutar, no se si me explico

Comment: @ Gerardo Marroquin @tecnobyte Funciono!!! gracias master..